# Plone @@usergroup-userprefs crashes with plone.app.ldap

Tags: python-2.7, plone, python-ldap

I have installed Plone 4.2.1 and plone.app.ldap 1.3. If the ldap server is activated, the ldap user can login, but the admin cannot access the `@@usergroup-userprefs` page. It throws up some errors as follows:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module plone.app.controlpanel.usergroups, line 198, in __call__
  Module plone.app.controlpanel.usergroups, line 224, in doSearch
  Module Products.PluggableAuthService.PluggableAuthService, line 211, in getUserById
  Module Products.PluggableAuthService.PluggableAuthService, line 794, in _verifyUser
  Module Products.LDAPMultiPlugins.LDAPMultiPlugin, line 190, in enumerateUsers
  Module Products.LDAPUserFolder.LDAPUserFolder, line 810, in getUserById
  Module Products.LDAPUserFolder.LDAPUserFolder, line 758, in getUserByAttr
IndexError: list index out of range
```

On disabling the ldap server, the admin can access the `@@usergroup-userprefs` page of the plone site.
OpenLDAP is also installed. When I run the command `$dpkg -l|grep OpenLDAP`, I get the follwing listing.

```
ii  ldap-utils                        2.4.23-7.3                   OpenLDAP utilities
ii  libldap-2.4-2                     2.4.23-7.3                   OpenLDAP libraries
ii  libldap2-dev                      2.4.23-7.3                   OpenLDAP development libraries
ii  slapd                             2.4.23-7.3                   OpenLDAP server (slapd)
```

Comment: Do you have the 'Many users?' option set on `@@usergroup-controlpanel`?

Comment: There is no such option that I can see here @http://stackoverflow.com/users/626302/dan-jacka

Comment: It might behelpful to know: 1. what attribute your users use to identify themselves, 2. what your setting is regarding using the manager DN. My wild guess is that your admin cannot read enough attributes from the LDAP server for the other people.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/505649/ulrich-schwarz ,the users are identified by uid and the manager DN is given the value cn=admin,dc=xyz,dc=com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the LDAP entries with uid and SN attribute are not populated for some of the users,or the uid includes space before or after the uid value. On a whole this problem occurs if the ldap data is not correctly added, then the above users and groups sub-menu in plone throws up errors as above.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that when I access the LDAPServer from ZMI, the server was not defined. I added the ldap server details there and it got connected. Looks like the LDAPServer does not get set from the GUI i.e LDAP control panel